# Is it possible to fetch HTML in a specific div in plaintext from a page after javascript loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js

currently working with the fetch function in a js script to pull HTML as plain text from a website so that I can convert a specific div to plaintext. Unfortunately, the specific div I want only loads after the JS on the page loads (i think?)

```
fetch(https://glossary.infil.net/?t=Safe%20Jump).then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function (html) {
        var def = //some way to isolate div with class def
        //remove HTML tags
        const cleanedDef = def.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        console.log(cleanedDef);
      })
```

Here, I want the text from the div with class ".def" from https://glossary.infil.net/?t=Safe%20Jump but it doesn't show up when I print the html to console.

Comment: `fetch()` will only fetch the HTML source code, it won't run the JS on the page.

Comment: To get the DIV, you can parse the HTML by loading it into a `DocumentFragment`, and then using methods like `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: How would I load it into a ```DocumentFragment``` and have the div show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert html response into a new element without inserting it into DOM and manipulate it's content from there:

```
fetch("https://glossary.infil.net/?t=Safe%20Jump").then(function(response) {
  return response.text();
}).then(function(html) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;
  var def = div.querySelector(".def"); //get element with class "def"
  console.log(def);
})
```